# Integration with respect to a Poisson random measure

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes, point-processes

Let $N$ be a Poisson random measure (PRM) on a Polish space, $\left(X,\mathcal{B}(X)\right)$,
and let $\tilde{\nu}$ be its mean measure. Then, let $f$ be any non
negative and bounded function on $X$. The following are equivalent:
$$
1. \int_{X}f(x)N(dx)<+\infty,\ a.s.;
$$

$$
2. \int_{X}\left(1-e^{-f(x)}\right)\tilde{\nu}(dx)<+\infty;
$$

$$
3. \int_{X}\min\left\{ \left|f(x)\right|,1\right\} \tilde{\nu}(dx)<+\infty.
$$
Why is it so?

Comment: Do you assume that $\bar{\nu}$ is a finite measure? Otherwise, the assertion does not hold true, as far as I can see (just choose $f := 0$).

Comment: I think that $\tilde{\nu}$ must be boundedly finite.

Comment: By the way, I see that 3. $\Rightarrow$ 2. is obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by "boundedly finite"? In general, $\bar{\nu}$ is just a $\sigma$-finite measure and then the assertion does not hold true.

Comment: I mean that $\tilde{\nu}$ must be finite on any finite set.

Comment: Well, but then the claim does not hold. If $\bar{\nu}(X)$ is not finite, the implication $1 \implies 3$ does not hold true (again, simply choose $f:=0$).

Comment: Absolutely right, so I think there must be some mistake in my lecture notes. So, in order to get the equivalence $\tilde{\nu}$ must be finite.

Comment: Wait, I found the mistake: the max in 3. was to be replaced with a min. Boundedly finite should be ok so far, right?

Comment: Please use the tag (point-processes) instead of the tag (poisson-random-measures) since the former encompasses the latter (whose creation was ill-advised).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) $\iff$ (2)

Since $f \geq 0$ is measurable, there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of simple functions (aka elemtary functions/step functions) such that $0 \leq f_n \uparrow f$. Each $f_n$ can be written in the form

$$f_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{N_n} c_{j,n} 1_{B_{j,n}}(x).$$

for suitable constants $c_{j,n} \geq 0$ and $B_{j,n} \in \mathcal{B}(X)$. Then

$$\int f_n(x) \, N(dx) = \sum_{j=1}^{N_n} c_{j,n} N(B_{j,n})$$

and using that $N$ is a Poisson random measure, we find

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \exp \left( - \lambda \int f_n(x) \, N(dx) \right) &= \prod_{j=1}^{N_n} \exp \left(- \bar{\nu}(B_{j,n}) (1-e^{-\lambda c_{j,n}}) \right) \\ &= \exp \left( - \int (1-e^{-\lambda f_n(x)}) \, \bar{\nu}(dx) \right) \end{align*}$$

Since $f \geq 0$ is non-negative we may apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \exp \left( - \lambda \int f(x) \, N(dx) \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \exp \left( -\lambda \int f_n(x) \, N(dx) \right) \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp \left( - \int (1-e^{-\lambda f_n(x)}) \, \bar{\nu}(dx) \right) \\ &= \exp \left( - \int (1-e^{-\lambda f(x)}) \, \bar{\nu}(dx) \right). \end{align*}$$
(Just as a side remark: This identity is also known as Campbell's formula.)

If $\int f(x) \, N(dx)<\infty$ almost surely, we know that the left-hand side is strictly positive and this, in turn, implies $\int (1-e^{-\lambda f(x)}) \, \bar{\nu}(dx)<\infty$. On the other hand, if $\int (1-e^{-\lambda f(x)}) \, \bar{\nu}(dx)<\infty$ for some $\lambda>0$, this implies that the right-hand side is strictly positive and so $\int f(x) \, N(dx)<\infty$ almost surely.

(3) $\implies$ (2)

Obviously, $0 \leq 1-e^{-y} \leq 1$ for any $y \geq 0$. On the other hand, it is not difficult to see (e..g from Taylor's formula) that $1-e^{-y} \leq y$ for all $y \geq 0$. Thus, $$1-e^{-y} \leq \min\{1,y\}$$ and using this estimate for $y=f(x)$ proves the assertion.

(2) $\implies$ (3)

Since $y \leq 2(1-e^{-y})$ for any $0 \leq  y \leq 1$, we have

$$\int_{|f(x)| \leq 1} |f(x)| \, \bar{\nu}(dx) \leq 2 \int_X (1-e^{-f(x)}) \, \bar{\nu}(dx)<\infty.$$

On the other hand, by the monotonicity of the mapping $y \mapsto 1-e^{-y}$,

$$\int_{|f(x)|>1} 1\, \bar{\nu}(dx) \leq \int_{|f(x)|>1} \frac{1-e^{-f(x)}}{1-e^{-1}} \, \bar{\nu}(dx) \leq \frac{1}{1-e^{-1}} \int_X(1-e^{-f(x)}) \, \bar{\nu}(dx)<\infty.$$

Consequently,
$$\int_X \min\{|f(x)|,1\} \, \bar{\nu}(dx)<\infty.$$